# How to open an EJS file with Live Server

Tags: visual-studio-code, server, ejs, nodejs-server

I have a Server App created with Nodejs using "ejs" view engine.

When I start the Server and is running on the port, I click the URL and it sends me to my APP with no problem.

When I try to do it with Live server is when I am facing issues.

In Live Server instructions says: [NOTE: In case if you don't have any .html or .htm file in your workspace then you have to follow method no 4 & 5 to start server.]

That is what I do and I get redirected to, please see image below:
[image]

Could any one help me with this issue, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: pic1]
You can see it here
i wrote app.listen(3000);
thats mean i can access from 3000 port on my browser.

[image: pic2]

like this.

Just write to your server.js "localhost:(your-port)"
and you are ready to go

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Thank you for tip. I'll careful next time.